# Need help to convert formula D=2∑ni=1{Ylog[YE(Y)]−[Y−E(Y)]} to python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I will need some help to convert a formula into a python code.

D=2∑ni=1{Ylog[YE(Y)]−[Y−E(Y)]}

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues have you encountered? To get you started you can use a for loop to emulate the sigma (ie `for i in range(1, n + 1)` or a list comprehension with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) `sum(i for i in range(1, n + 1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you've solved the issue of computing the mean of a random variable like Y. So, i'm assuming that you have something called `mean(sample: list)` which receives a list of values taken by the R.V. (Random Variable) Y.

Now, to convert the formula into code, there may be many ways. I personally prefer the ones that are easier to read and follow.

```
import math


sample = [] # Whatever values your RV takes
mean_of_Y = mean(sample)
D = 0

# This part will make the summation - obs stands for observation
for obs in sample:
    D += obs*math.log(obs/mean_of_Y, 10) - (obs - mean_of_Y)
    # I made the assumption that the log's base is 10

# Now we need to multiply it by 2
D = D*2

# If you want to see it
print(D)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
ys = [1,2,3] # 3 classes
expectation = {
    1 : 2.718281828459045, 
    2 : 7.38905609893065,
    3 : 20.085536923187668,
}
#i have given exponent value as expectation in the example, some sample values
    
D = sum([((y * math.log(y/expectation[y])) - (y - expectation[y])) for y in ys]) * 2
```

Expected value is differ for discrete and continous random variable.

If the expected value is discrete, the expected value can be calculated as follows,
[image]

P(Y=y) can be calculated by [Probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function)

If the expected value is continous, the expected value can be calculated as follows,
[image]

Where the Fy(Y) can be calculated  by [Probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and (a,b) is the range of the values